# Send MSGPack body generates HTTP 500

Tags: http, msgpack, insomnia

I actualy try to replicate a http request with a msgpack body request. I have the original request that works (several times testet, generates a http 200 statuscode) [image: Fiddler request]

If i replicate the request for example in insomnia or in PowerShell or with curl i get an http error 500. I tried it with a binary file also as Body.
Any ideas?

Following curl command can be use:

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://4af7c20b-7646-4fb7-b64f-ae0a8c51c1f1.register.collector.scopely.io/register \
  --header 'Accept: application/x-msgpack' \
  --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' \
  --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  --header 'Connection: Keep-Alive' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-msgpack' \
  --header 'Host: 4af7c20b-7646-4fb7-b64f-ae0a8c51c1f1.register.collector.scopely.io' \
  --header 'User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-N950N Build/NMF26X)' \
  --header 'X-Unity-Version: 5.6.4p3' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-length: 672' \
  --header 'x-scopely-titan-auth: 4af7c20b-7646-4fb7-b64f-ae0a8c51c1f1' \
  --body 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
```

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the curl command that used?

Comment: Hi shao, i added the curl command